# HTTP POST to form truncating preceding 0's in text field

Tags: php, forms, textfield

We're trying to post a phone number to a field that automatically parses the numbers between area code, prefix and number.  If the number starts with a 0 then the fields are truncating it.  These are text fields.  Is there something we can put in the string to format this correctly?  The post looks like ....;PH=8882220055; and when posted shows correctly up to the 0055 number.

Comment: Are you sure these are text fields? It sounds like they're `type="number"`.

Comment: Show your HTML and parsing code.